# Is there a simpler way to get windows build tools (vcbuild.ex or msbuild.exe)?

Tags: windows, node.js, sails.js

Working with nodejs + sailsjs framework. Installing sails involves certain dependencies that build binaries. To do this on windows you need vcbuild.exe and the only way I know of to get it is to install Visual Studio Express (which installs `vcbuild.dll`'s) and a Windows SDK . . . 3gb of data an ~2hrs later, I have the one exe that I need.

Is there a simpler solution?